# C++17 Best way to build operators with variant on two sides?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++17, variant, visitor-pattern

I have a project that use a `std::variant` for a variable length types :

```
using Length = std::variant<int, long, float, double, Fraction>;
```

The `Fraction` class already overload most of the operators.

I want to create arithmetics operators like :

```
Length operator+ (Length lhs, Length rhs);
Length operator- (Length lhs, Length rhs);
Length operator* (Length lhs, Length rhs);
Length operator/ (Length lhs, Length rhs);
```

But comparison operators too :

```
Length operator== (Length lhs, Length rhs);
Length operator!= (Length lhs, Length rhs);

Length operator>  (Length lhs, Length rhs);
Length operator>= (Length lhs, Length rhs);
Length operator<  (Length lhs, Length rhs);
Length operator<= (Length lhs, Length rhs);
```

This is the pattern I use to do the job with `std::visit` method.

```
Length operator* (Length lhs, Length rhs)
{
    Length res;

    std::visit([&res, rhs](auto& left)
    {
        using T = std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(left)>>;

        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)
        {
            std::visit([&res, left](auto& right)
            {
                using T = std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(right)>>;

                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)       { res = left * right; } else
                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, long>)      { res = left * right; } else
                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, float>)     { res = left * right; } else
                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, double>)    { res = left * right; } else
                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Fraction>)  { res = left * right; }
            },
            rhs);
        } 
        else
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, long>)
        {
            std::visit([&res, left](auto& right)
            {
                using T = std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(right)>>;

                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)       { res = left * right; } else
                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, long>)      { res = left * right; } else
                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, float>)     { res = left * right; } else
                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, double>)    { res = left * right; } else
                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Fraction>)  { res = left * right; }
            },
            rhs);
        } 
        else
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, float>)
        {
            std::visit([&res, left](auto& right)
            {
                using T = std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(right)>>;

                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)       { res = left * right; } else
                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, long>)      { res = left * right; } else
                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, float>)     { res = left * right; } else
                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, double>)    { res = left * right; } else
                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Fraction>)  { res = left * right; }
            },
            rhs);
        } 
        else
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, double>)
        {
            std::visit([&res, left](auto& right)
            {
                using T = std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(right)>>;

                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)       { res = left * right; } else
                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, long>)      { res = left * right; } else
                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, float>)     { res = left * right; } else
                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, double>)    { res = left * right; } else
                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Fraction>)  { res = left * right; }
            },
            rhs);
        } 
        else
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Fraction>)
        {
            std::visit([&res, left](auto& right)
            {
                using T = std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(right)>>;

                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)       { res = left * right; } else
                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, long>)      { res = left * right; } else
                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, float>)     { res = left * right; } else
                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, double>)    { res = left * right; } else
                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Fraction>)  { res = left * right; }
            },
            rhs);
        }
    },
    lhs);

    return res;
}
```

That works, but this is redundant, non esthetic, and probably not so fast to do large operation process.

Comment: You use `if constexpr` to be able to discard branches that would have been ill-formed. In your case, they are the exact same, so no need for branching at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your operands are of the variant type, just [visit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) them both together:

```
Length operator* (Length lhs, Length rhs)
{
  return std::visit([](auto const &l, auto const &r) -> Length {
    return l * r;
  }, lhs, rhs);
}
```

The standard library already performs the required logic for you.

Comment: Oh yes. Very quick answer and very good answer. I love that. Thank you so much.

Comment: It seem that VS2017 do not like this syntax ? I get some specializations errors : C2672 / C2143 / C2893

Comment: @MaximeCoorevits - I mistyped the location of `&`. I need to more coffee. Does it work now?

Comment: Sorry, I was on phone right now. And yes, this is the tip, i've just copy your code without checking that.  Compile and run now. Thank you so much.